Two series converges pointwise to same limit, and one converges uniformly
We have $\sum{f_n}$ and $\sum{g_n}$.
$f_n,g_n$:[0,1]->$\mathbb{R}$ and all f are non-negative and all g are continuous. Both series converges pointwise to the same limit. How to prove that if $\sum g_n$converges uniformly, then second series also converges uniformly? Weierstrass test can't work here, Abel and Dirichlet also. So it appears that this proof comes from Cauchy uniform criterion, but I don't have idea how to manipulate definitions to get this proof.

I don't see any counterexamples

And by pointwise convergence I meant that for all x, $\sum f_n=\sum g_n$

Sorry. I was thinking of the domain as $\mathbb R$. For $[0,1]$ this is true. Apply Dini's Theorem to $M-(f_1+f_2+...+f_n)$ for a suitable constant $M$.

Ref. for Dini's Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem

Oh thanks, that's right I forgot about this theorem, but I don't fully understand this idea. From Dino's theorem we know that $f_n$ uniformly converges, how does this guarantee that sequence of partial sums converges uniformly? And how are we using $\sum g_n$?

It is $f_1+f_2+...+f_n$, not $f_n$, that converges uniformly by Dini' Theorem.

Ohh I see this now, and g is for continuous limit, right?

Yes, the only thing you need about $g_n$ and $g$ is the fact that $\sum f_n=\sum g_n$ is a  continuous function.

Thanks for help, I'm closing this question
